# Wie sagt man "Hope for the best and prepare for the worst" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie kann man den englischen Spruch "[Hope for the best and prepare for the worst](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Hope+for+the+best+and+prepare+for+the+worst)" elegant ins Deutsche übersetzen? Mein Versuch:

> Hoff auf das Beste und bereite dich auf das Schlimmste vor.

Ist es korrekt, den Imperativ hier zu verwenden? Es scheint irgendwie nicht richtig, denn wenn man formell sein wollte, müsste man dann "Hoffen Sie ... bereiten Sie sich ..." sagen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hier den Imperativ zu verwenden, entspricht der grundsätzlichen Natur solcher Aphorismen am ehesten.
(Dabei würde ich "hoff**e**" empfehlen.) Als unpersönlicher Imperativ:

> Man sollte (immer) (auf) das Beste hoffen, doch auf das Schlimmste vorbereitet sein.

"Grundform" mit Infinitiven:

> das Beste hoffen, doch auf das Schlimmste vorbereitet sein

Comment: Das ist eine Übersetzung, aber nicht idiomatisch.

Answer (score 5):

Hoffe auf das Beste, doch rechne mit dem Schlimmsten.

Answer (score 2):

I know the following saying is sometimes used in the German army:

> "Das Beste hoffen, das Schlimmste erwarten"

However, erwarten is "expect", not "prepare", so it's not a literal translation.

Answer (score 0):

Im Deutschen gibt es "Wir hoffen das Beste und sind aufs Schlimmste gefasst."

Im Imperativ fällt mir keine direkte Entsprechung ein.

Answer (score -2):

Dann bleib auch bei der "Grundform"...

> `Das Beste hoffen, auf das Schlimmste vorbereiten.`

DAS ist die korrekte Übersetzung des Spruchs.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Aufgrund des reklamierten Anspruchs, das dies die einzig korrekte Lösung sei: Gibt es dazu eine Quelle? Ansonsten schlage ich eine neutralere Formulierung (auch neutraler "Dann bleib auch...") vor.